# I am getting multiple postbacks on messenger bot when used in mobile, but works fine when running on web?

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I have created a bot which works completely fine when running on web, getting one callback on each click of button. When i test the same bot on mobile device i get exactly three postbacks for one tap. How is this happening?

Comment: I've also just noticed the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug (see details here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/266270213720379/). It apparently affects only the Android Messenger chat app and not iOS. I'm testing on Android, so I think this is definitely what I'm hitting. They say the bug will be fixed with the next Android Messenger update.